# How to convert rows from SQL query to columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot

I have the SQL query which generates a table with users and their answers for the task numbers:

[image: Current result]

Which SQL query should I use to get something like this:

[image: Required result]

I have 50 question numbers and about 1500 users. Unfortunately, it seems to me that simple SELECT and GROUP BY cannot do here.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select username,
       max(answer) filter (where task_number = 1) as task_1,
       max(answer) filter (where task_number = 2) as task_2
from t
group by username;
```

Comment: It works! Thank you very much! But, could you explain why we should use max(answers)?

Comment: @VladDeryabkin . . . There is only one row that matches the filtering conditions.  You need an aggregation function, so `max()` is as good as any such function.